# Using MySQL syntax to select based on unique columns?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database with a listing for every city in the US based on zip code. By nature it has a city/state listing for every zip code in the US which produces several city/state duplicates. I want to perform a SELECT that returns a single row for each city/state.

I have included a screenshot of the database structure for reference. `num` is PRIMARY.

What would the syntax be for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) can do this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT city, state FROM table_name;
```

Comment: This seems to be the faster of the two queries by far, which would seem to support the information I've found online regarding the speed differences as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is simply to group by the city, then by the state (in case there are overlaps on city names across states):

```
SELECT * FROM ziptable GROUP BY city, state
```